# How to deploy a webapplication developed to a remotely running tomcat server?

Tags: apache, tomcat

I need to deploy a webapplication developed in my local system (used Eclipse) on a tomcat server running on a remote server. For this what all privilages are to be needed on the existing server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version of Tomcat are you using? You should just be able to go to manager screen and deploy your war file from there i.e. http://hostname:8080/manager

On Tomcat 7 you need to have a user entry in /conf/tomcat-users.xml for the role manager-gui.

If you can connect to the server hosting tomcat you could copy your war file to the webapps directory manually instead.

Comment: ya thank you, I am using tomcat 7.0.22. The server is running on a linux system

Comment: Urm, what happened here. Why has this been unmarked as the correct answer? You've moved the tick to the same answer posted a month later.

Answer (score 0):

the easy way to deploy the application is to make a war file of your application and paste it in the webapps folder of tomcat installation folder. By default it catalina_home/webapps
or use the inbuilt hostmanager application.

Comment: Can you explain how to configure tomcat for running manager app

Comment: Thats easy add the below line to your tomcat-users.xml '<user name="username" password="password" roles="admin-gui,manager-gui" />'

Comment: What has this answer added? It's the same as the original correct answer just a month late.